# Error con la inyección de una dependencia

Tags: java, jsf, inyeccion-de-dependencias

primera vez que recurro aquí. Estoy incursionando en el Mundo de JSF, estoy intentando implementar algo nuevo para mí que es la inyección de dependencias. Soy autodidacta, disculpen si mi pregunta es un poco tonta o si no sigo un patrón determinado. Insisto con que estoy aprendiendo:

Aquí mi código:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Registrar Usuario</title>
    
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h2>Registrar Nuevo Usuario</h2>
    <h:form>
        
        <p>
            <h:outputLabel for="id">ID:</h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="id" value="#{usuMB.id}" required="true" />
        </p>
        
        <!-- Aquí agregarías más campos para otros atributos del usuario -->
        <p>
            <h:commandButton value="Eliminar" action="#{usuMB.borrarUsuario()}" /> 
        </p>
    </h:form>
    
    
    
</h:body>
</html>

package modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.ejb.EJB;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
@Entity
@Named(value = "usuMB")

public class UsuarioManagedBean implements Serializable {

    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "Legajo")
    private int Legajo;
    @Column(name = "Apellido")
    private String Apellido;
    @Column(name = "Nombre")
    private String Nombre;
    @Column(name = "Tipo_Documento")
    private String Tipo_Documento;
    @Column(name = "Nro_Documento")
    private int Nro_Documento;
    @Column(name = "Sexo")
    private String Sexo;
    @Column(name = "Nacimiento")
    private String Nacimiento;
    @Column(name = "Clase")
    private String Clase;
    @Column(name = "Cuil_Cuit")
    private String Cuit_Cuil;
    @Column(name = "Lugar_De_Nacimiento")
    private String Lugar_De_Nacimiento;
    @Column(name = "Nacionalidad")
    private String Nacionalidad;
    @Column(name = "Estado_Civil")
    private String Estado_Civil;
    @Column(name = "Mail")
    private String Mail;
    @Column(name = "Telefono")
    private String Telefono;
    @Column(name = "Observaciones")
    private String Observaciones;
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getLegajo() {
        return Legajo;
    }

    public void setLegajo(int Legajo) {
        this.Legajo = Legajo;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return Apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String Apellido) {
        this.Apellido = Apellido;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String Nombre) {
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
    }

    public String getTipo_Documento() {
        return Tipo_Documento;
    }

    public void setTipo_Documento(String Tipo_Documento) {
        this.Tipo_Documento = Tipo_Documento;
    }

    public int getNro_Documento() {
        return Nro_Documento;
    }

    public void setNro_Documento(int Nro_Documento) {
        this.Nro_Documento = Nro_Documento;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return Sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String Sexo) {
        this.Sexo = Sexo;
    }

    public String getNacimiento() {
        return Nacimiento;
    }

    public void setNacimiento(String Nacimiento) {
        this.Nacimiento = Nacimiento;
    }

    public String getClase() {
        return Clase;
    }

    public void setClase(String Clase) {
        this.Clase = Clase;
    }

    public String getCuit_Cuil() {
        return Cuit_Cuil;
    }

    public void setCuit_Cuil(String Cuit_Cuil) {
        this.Cuit_Cuil = Cuit_Cuil;
    }

    public String getLugar_De_Nacimiento() {
        return Lugar_De_Nacimiento;
    }

    public void setLugar_De_Nacimiento(String Lugar_De_Nacimiento) {
        this.Lugar_De_Nacimiento = Lugar_De_Nacimiento;
    }

    public String getNacionalidad() {
        return Nacionalidad;
    }

    public void setNacionalidad(String Nacionalidad) {
        this.Nacionalidad = Nacionalidad;
    }

    public String getEstado_Civil() {
        return Estado_Civil;
    }

    public void setEstado_Civil(String Estado_Civil) {
        this.Estado_Civil = Estado_Civil;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return Mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String Mail) {
        this.Mail = Mail;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return Telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String Telefono) {
        this.Telefono = Telefono;
    }

    public String getObservaciones() {
        return Observaciones;
    }

    public void setObservaciones(String Observaciones) {
        this.Observaciones = Observaciones;
    }
    
    public UsuarioManagedBean(int id, int Legajo, String Apellido, String Nombre, String Tipo_Documento, int Nro_Documento, String Sexo, String Nacimiento, String Clase, String Cuit_Cuil, String Lugar_De_Nacimiento, String Nacionalidad, String Estado_Civil, String Mail, String Telefono, String Observaciones) {
        this.id = id;
        this.Legajo = Legajo;
        this.Apellido = Apellido;
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.Tipo_Documento = Tipo_Documento;
        this.Nro_Documento = Nro_Documento;
        this.Sexo = Sexo;
        this.Nacimiento = Nacimiento;
        this.Clase = Clase;
        this.Cuit_Cuil = Cuit_Cuil;
        this.Lugar_De_Nacimiento = Lugar_De_Nacimiento;
        this.Nacionalidad = Nacionalidad;
        this.Estado_Civil = Estado_Civil;
        this.Mail = Mail;
        this.Telefono = Telefono;
        this.Observaciones = Observaciones;
    }
    
    
    
    public UsuarioManagedBean() {
    }
    
    
    @PersistenceContext(name = "jsfPU")
    
    @EJB
    private UsuarioServiceBean usu;
    
    public void borrarUsuario(){
        
        usu.eliminarUsuario(id);
    }
    
    
}
```

---

```
package modelo;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;


@Stateless
public class UsuarioServiceBean {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "jsfPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void guardarUsuario(UsuarioManagedBean usuario) {
        entityManager.persist(usuario);
    }

    public UsuarioManagedBean obtenerUsuarioPorId(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(UsuarioManagedBean.class, id);
    }



public List<UsuarioManagedBean> obtenerTodosLosUsuarios() {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM UsuarioManagedBean u", UsuarioManagedBean.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public void actualizarUsuario(UsuarioManagedBean usuario) {
        entityManager.merge(usuario);
    }

    public void eliminarUsuario(int id) {
        UsuarioManagedBean usuario = entityManager.find(UsuarioManagedBean.class, id);
        if (usuario != null) {
            entityManager.remove(usuario);
        }
    }
}
```

---

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>proyectojsf</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>proyectojsf</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.asm</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version> <!-- Puedes especificar la versión que necesites -->
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.SP1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.20</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.20</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
    </dependency>
   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version> <!-- Ajusta la versión según tus necesidades -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.33</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

Bueno, el error dice: "basic attributes can only be of the following types" en la linea "private UsuarioServiceBean usu;". El proyecto me compila, hago click en el botón y lanza el error: "/index.xhtml @15,72 value="#{usuMB.id}": Objetivo inalcanzable, identificador [usuMB] resuelto a nulo".

Usé también la etiqueta @Inject en un principio, luego cambié a @EJB (leí por ahí que Tomcat es un contenedor de servlets y no un contenedor de EJB.. También cambié la versión de IDE, estaba usando Netbeans 17 y pasé al 13 ya que no me aparecían los recurso de JavaServerFaces, todo muy raro.

No sé si brindar algún dato más, estaba usando JSP y por eso decidí comenzar otro proyecto pero con jsf. Mi idea luego es pasar a Srping, pero primero quería pispear ésta tecnología. Agradezco a quienes se tomen el tiempo en ayudarme, desde ya mil gracias!

Answer (score 0):

¿Donde defines usuMD?

Deberías tener algún tipo de controlador donde definas el usuMD y desde donde inyectes la dependencia al servicio.

La idea general es HTML->Controlador->Servicio-..->BBDD

Algo así ... perdona pero lo escribo de memoria y habrá erratas

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UsuarioController implements Serializable(){
   Usuario usuMD;   // con su get-set
   @EJB
   UsuarioServiceBean usuarioServiceBean

 public UsuarioController(){}

 public void borrarUsuario(){    // <- Aqui es donde accedes desde HTML
     usuarioServiceBan.delete();
 }

}
```